# How to use cmake GLOB_RECURSE for only some subdirectories

Tags: cmake

I have a source code layout that looks like this:

```
TopDir/
    CMakeLists.txt
    A.cpp
    A.hpp
    ...
    File/
        F1.cpp
        F1.hpp
        ...
    Section/
        S1.cpp
        S1.hpp
        ...
    Test/
        CMakeLists.txt
        TestF1S1.cpp
        TestF2S2.cpp
        ...
```

I want to capture all the `.cpp` files as source files (`ENDF6_SRC`), so in my `TopDir/CMakeLists.txt` file, I have a line that looks like this:

```
file(GLOB_RECURSE ENDF6_SRC ${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR} *.cpp)
```

This grabs all the `.cpp` files in `TopDir/`, `File/`, `Section/` as expected, but also grabs all the `.cpp` files in `Test/` as well.

**How can I create my `ENDF6_SRC` variable without adding the `.cpp` files from the `Test` directory?** I don't want a `CMakeLists.txt` file in `File/` or `Section/`.

Answer (score 53, accepted):

If you don't have subdirectories inside "TopDir/File" or "TopDir/Section", you can do:

```
file(GLOB ENDF6_SRC
       ${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/*.cpp
       ${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/File/*.cpp
       ${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/Section/*.cpp)
```

If you *do* have subdirectories there, you'll need more than one call:

```
file(GLOB ENDF6_SRC_TOP
       ${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/*.cpp)
file(GLOB_RECURSE ENDF6_SRC_NESTED
       ${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/File/*.cpp
       ${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/Section/*.cpp)
set(ENDF6_SRC ${ENDF6_SRC_TOP} ${ENDF6_SRC_NESTED})
```

By the way, doing `file(GLOB_RECURSE ...)` in your top-level directory will likely pick up unwanted cpp files from the build folder too in the case of an in-source build (i.e. where the build root is inside "TopDir").

Answer (score 15):

You can also exclude Test dir by filtering the globbed list :

```
file(GLOB_RECURSE ENDF6_SRC ${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR} *.cpp)
list(FILTER ENDF6_SRC EXCLUDE REGEX "${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/Test/.*" )
```